# Can I set up WCF data service and WebAPI method at the same URL

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api

We are looking at combining Odata and WebAPI to create an api. one of the things I am looking at is mapping a OData data service to the same URL as a WebApi controller. We could use the power of OData and its query support to provide read only information. and then use the WebApi controller methods to accept Updates. In this way we can have greater control of any updates that are sent into the system.
So far I have attempted to do this with routeing.

```
DataServiceHostFactory factory = new DataServiceHostFactory();
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("api/SDAApi", factory, typeof(ReadService)));
```

So I am adding a Route to my ReadService which is the Odata Data service. The SDAApi matches my controller name.
On my controller I have a method SoftwareDownloadRequestsPost which matches the collection I am requesting from the ReadService - SoftwareDownloadRequests.

When I do a get at the url ~/Api/SDAApi/SoftwareDownloadRequests in my browser I get the expected list of items. How ever when I do a post to the url with a simple form post I get a response. 
"The content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' is not supported."
Since this form post worked when I had it at a different url I am assuming it is caused by the conflict.

So back to my question, is this possible? and if it is any ideas on how to fix my error?

I am using VS 2012 RC and .NET 4.5

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of a good reason you would want to do this.

ASP.NET Web API exposes some important functionality of OData (for example $filter) in RC. Apparently more support is coming in future releases although maybe not in RTM.

Comment: I have not heard that they have any intention to increase the level of OData functionality in WebApi, so that is great news if they do.

Comment: @Noel http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/359229. By the way, you do not vote up, down or mark as answer. That is **not good**.

Comment: I missed the 5 minute editing window, but I would go on to say - At this time it’s a poor man’s implementation, with a modest amount of functionality and a fairly big issue for me, which is in the WebApi, the query is not pushed down to the database as it is in OData.  Perhaps this is a solvable problem; I have not really looked at it.

Comment: Hey I am trying to be a good community member, I actually went back this morning and looked at my questions and from my perspective I just have not received answers that satisfied my questions. I can see this could be a failure on my part to write good questions, but I dont think it fair to either vote up or down if I dont beleive it was a good answer.